# How to override the long key press functionality in android?

Tags: android

can anyone tell me how can we overide the long key press functionalty of menu key? 
       I have to call an activity on long press on menu key for device samsung galaxy S.
       Please tell me how can implement that...some sample code is appreciable.

Comment: did you mean pressing menu key everywhere or in a particular application?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
           System.out.println("......menu is clicked...");
       }
    return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: I have already tried this thing..but when i am pressing menu key for long ..then default search functionlaty is calling . debugger never comes inside this function..do i need to implement any listener....please tell me hiw can i disable this default search functionalty call.

Answer (score 0):

override `onLongKeyPress()` method...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {


       if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU){
           //your stuff
       }
    return true;
//you should return true at last
}
```

Comment: not working..default functionalty is calling on long press of meny key

Comment: @ntc..can u please share me that answer link.

Comment: @pankajsatwal.. there are no links to it,.. you can refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyLongPress%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29